# netcat-like simultaneous read/write on a socket?

Tags: c

I'm in the process of learning how to do networking in C. I want to implement a simple netcat-like program for educational purposes. Something I can't figure out how to implement, however, is the program simultaneously reading input from stdin/writing it to the connection, and reading data from the connection/printing it to stdout.

I came up with a potential solution: spawn a child process using `fork()` that reads data from the connection and writes it to stdout, while the parent process handles reading data from the user and writing it to the connection.

The code I wrote to implement this doesn't work and is probably in violation of several safety practices, but it's just a proof of concept to show my idea.

```c
if (fork() == 0) {
    char line[1024];

    for (;;) {
        memset(line, 0, 1024);

        n = read(fd, line, 1023);

        if (n)
            fputs(line, stdout);
    }
} else {
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            write(fd, "\r\n", 2);
        else
            write(fd, &c, 1);
    }
}
```

Is there a canonical way to do something like this in C?

Comment: `man 2 select` is your friend. This is best done with two buffers, a `select` loop, and a single thread. If you're on the Windows platform, prepare for headache. 99% of your problems will be making standard input and output behave.

Comment: `read` can return -1 and -1 is true in boolean terms. So `if (n)` is buggy. What's the actual problem you're experiencing?